# Is ths considered a MySQL array?

Tags: mysql

I am pretty comfortable with basic MySQL commands, as well as complex joins, but not sure about this array or data type that I have come across.

The code looks like:

```
 a:4:{i:9888;s:0:"";i:17148;s:0:"";i:9879;s:0:"";i:9881;s:0:"";}
 a:1:{i:9857;s:0:"";}
 a:0:{}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of the following:

1. What is this called?
2. How can I do some basic commands without PHP to loop through?  Such as get everything 
   where A is greater than 1?
3. Getting every row that includes 9857.

Comment: That looks like a PHP [serialized object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). A string representation of a complex object. Think of it like strongly typed JSON.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "mysql array". Arrays do not exist in relational databases. There's "sets" of data. Those are serialized **PHP** arrays.

Comment: You have those PHP serialized object strings in your database?

Comment: To see how they work, in PHP do `print_r(unserialize('a:4:{i:9888;s:0:"";i:17148;s:0:"";i:9879;s:0:"";i:9881;s:0:"";}'));`

Comment: @MarcB Arrays *do* exist in relational databases ([ex1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm), [ex2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html), [ex3 implied](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)).. even if not [always] appropriate tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is php serialized values: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

AFAIK, you cannot directly deserialize it from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the explanation what the string actually is, I'm telling you about an array in MySQL.

**In fact, it doesn't exist.** You could build a dirty kind of array by using `dynamic columns` but it's really, *really dirty*.
There is also [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) and `ENUM` which translate a (predefined-) *set* of data into a bitmask. I am working on an online shop with several hundreds of tables we didn't use ENUM and SET once.

A **proper way** of implementing arrays in MySQL is a **many-to-many** or any "many" related relation **between entities**.

*A Car having **several** Wheels (an **array** of wheels!)? Several Wheels attached to a single Car?*

You would build two tables and connect them through a `foreign key` to implement an *array*. Tho this is not a "datatype" *kind of array*, but a "relation" array.